# How to use Entity Framework Code First with events and EventHandler

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

Tengo una aplicacion de escritorio con este evento:

```
this.machineCreated += MachineCreatedHandler;
machineCreated();
```

y me esta dando este error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Yo inyecte el contexto asi

```
    services.AddDbContext<VisualDProviderContext>(options =>
                    options.UseMySql(connectionString, ServerVersion.AutoDetect(connectionString)),
                    ServiceLifetime.Transient);
```

este es mi handler

```
private async void MachineCreatedHandler()
        {
            listBox1.Items.Clear();
            allMachines = await machineService.GetAllMachines();
            selectedMachines = allMachines.OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList();
            foreach (var machine in allMachines.OrderBy(x => x.Name))
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(machine.Name);
            }
        }
```

Comment: una disculpa hecho

Comment: Según la [documentación oficial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/async): *EF Core doesn't support multiple parallel operations being run on the same context instance*. Cambia la línea por un simple `return await _context.Machines.ToListAsync();` y nos dices si funciona

Comment: Por cierto, hay alguna razón en específico por qué estás utilizando `Task.Run()` ? Si la hay, me gustaría saberla, ya que no había visto esa forma de programar antes.

Comment: Una cosa más. En el `GetMachineById()`, puedes utilizar `return _context.Machines.FirstOrDefault(machine => machine.Id == machineId)`; que te devuelve null en caso que no la encuentre; luego es cosa de hacer un nullcheck: `var machine = GetMachineById(id) ?? new Machine();`.

Comment: Lo último es que cambies el título de tu pregunta por algo más adecuado. *"Cómo usar EF con EventHandler"* no tiene NADA que ver con el cuerpo de tu pregunta. Tampoco le ayuda a nadie en el sitio que tenga problemas al ejecutar transacciones en paralelo con EF.

Comment: @Arriel hola pude resolver mi problema lo que tuve que hacer fue mover la creacion de evento en lugar de ponerlo en el contructor de la forma lo movi al evento load de la forma